# How to make a histogram from tibble df 3x2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, tibble

I need help making an histogram from a 3x2 tibble. I averaged the 3 samples in each group (Expt and Ctrl) and now trying to plot their histograms in the same plot. Also, I would like to add a legend that contains the coloring and name of each group.

Getting an error:
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (3): y

Tible looks like this. 3x2

control.average      exp.average

[-0.01280627,      -1.014465]

[99.93987077,       10.009083]

[6.02685326,        3.995733]

```
library(ggplot2)
# Create Histogram
ggplot(sample.average, aes(x = rownames(sample.average), y = colnames(sample.average))) + geom_histogram()+ stat = "identity"+ position = "dodge"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you have in your data frame.
This should get you started as well you can do `help(ggplot)` to read the help manual.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = exp.average, y = control.average, fill=factor(index))) + geom_histogram(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Group")) + labs(x = "Experimenatal", y="Control")
```

## Output

[image: output_dummy]

## data

```r
df <- structure(list(control.average = c(-0.01280627, 99.93987077, 
6.02685326), exp.average = c(-1.014465, 10.009083, 3.995733), 
    index = c(1, 2, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Hope it helps.